# Is there a way to define a shortcut elif to replace else if?

Tags: c++, if-statement, keyword

Is there a way to use the shortcut `elif` for `else if` ?

I was thinking of a typedef or whatever you would call it; Something like

```
typedef else if elif
```

in order to write

```
if (some_condition)
     dothis();
elif (some_other_condition)
     dothat();
```

Comment: First, don't. Second, why?

Comment: If you think that is a good idea use a preprocessor macro.

Comment: This is a common anti-pattern developers new to C/C++ make. The power of the pre-processor makes it seemingly cool to redefine the language. In practice, you'd never want to do this - it will just confuse the heck out of anyone else reading your code.

Comment: Yes:  `#define elif else if`.  However, since `elif` is not a C++ keyword, it will confuse people who read your code.

Comment: Why would you even want that? No other C++ programmer will be able to read your code if you start making up your own Frankenstein-language.

Comment: BTW, you should review the purpose of `else`.  The `else` section of code is run when the `if` condition is `false`.  Also, search the internet for "MISRA c++ terminating else"

Comment: All these comments show that this is a valid question:  OP is trying to achieve something that appears to be an anti-pattern.  So dear SO fellows, please explain him/her how to do it or why not to do it.  Down-votes because it's a bad idea is unfair for OP and will not help the community :-)

Answer (score 4):

In C and C++ it is possible to define the meaning of symbols very easily with the help of preprocessor [`#define`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx) directives:

```
#define elif else if
```

Such a definition will ensure a simple string substitution that the preprocessor will do before the compiler will start its job.

**But be very careful:**  This is known as a bad practice:

- readers will be confused by a non-standard language structure
- syntax highlighting editors cannot do their job properly anymore
- code that used a symbol `elif` for a variable or a function will no longer compile
- you miss the opportunity to get acquainted with the standard language and will keep being uncomfortable when yourself will read "else if" chains in code written by others
- you'll have to make sure that all your code either make this define or include your own header.

**So I recommend you not to go this way**, even it if looks cool or it reminds you other languages.  If you choose C++ accept its syntax. Embrace its syntax. Learn its idioms.  This is the best way to enjoy all its benefits.